# Show table when submit button pressed

Tags: html, button, html-table

I have a table on my page, and I want to know if it is possible to have a table hidden and then displayed when a button is clicked?
My table:

```
<table border="5",th,td, cellspacing="5", cellpadding="5", width="500", align="center">
            <tr>
                <th>TP ID</th>
                <th>Permit Deny</th>
                <th>Level</th>
                <th>Session</th>
                <th>Information Specialist</th>
            </tr>

            <?php foreach ($results as $row): ?>

            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row->TP_ID ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->Permit_or_Deny ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->Level ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->Session ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->Information_specialist ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach ?>

        </table>
```

Comment: Yes through the use of Javascript or jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this two ways, first is using PHP:

```
<?php
$action = $_GET['action'];
if ($action == "table") {
echo "Your table goes here"; //The table you want to display
}
else
{
echo '<html><form action="?action=table"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>'; //The submit button
}
?>
```

And the second method is using javascript with jQuery:

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<button href="#collapse" class="nav-toggle">Show</button>
<div id="collapse" style="display:none">
    <p>Your Table Goes Here</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav-toggle').click(function () {
        var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');
        var toggle_switch = $(this);
        $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function () {
            if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
                toggle_switch.html('Show');
            } else {
                toggle_switch.html('Hide');
            }
        });
    });

});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Starfire1337/33ygT/

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you can do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vVsAn/2113/

Jquery:

```
 $('#showHide').live('click', function(event) {        
         $('#hideShowDiv').toggle('hide');
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id='hideShowDiv'>
    Put your table inside a div <br />
</div>
<input type='button' id='showHide' value='hide/show'>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I ned the table to be hidden from default and then shown?

Comment: Then all you would need to do is set the style to the div to `display:none;` and then instead of `.toggle('hide');` you would have `.toggle('show');`